# Rotational Dynamics equation from non inertial frames

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

Suppose instead of writing torque = Ic*alpha from the centre of mass, I want to write it from another non inertial frame. I know L = Lcm + RxPcm from any other frame , so  if Idifferentiate it wrt time it'll give me the torque about that point. It gave me this:
T = Tcm + RxMA where R is the position vector of com wrt the point and A is the relative acceleration of the com. Now I know how to calculate moment of inertia about any point, but I am unsure how to relate the angular acceleration of the body wrt the frame with these two quantities. I think for writing T=I*alpha, the point must be on the rigid body. But what if it weren't?

Answer (score 1):

The uncoupled translational and rotational acceleration equations of motion

$$\begin{aligned}
m \boldsymbol a &= \sum_i \boldsymbol F_i \\
\mathbf I \frac{d\boldsymbol\omega}{dt} &= \sum_i \boldsymbol \tau_i - \boldsymbol \omega\times(\mathbf I \times \boldsymbol \omega)
\end{aligned}$$
is only valid for rotation about the center of mass. If you choose any other point as the point of interest, you'll need to use the much more complex [Newton-Euler equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Euler_equations). When using these more complicated forms, it doesn't matter a bit if the point of interest is chosen to be inside or outside the body.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**The equations of motion**

**Translation**

\begin{align*}
  &m\,\ddot{\vec{R}}=\sum_{cm} F\qquad(1)\\
  &\text{with:}\\
  &\vec{R}_o=\vec{R}+S\,\vec{u}\\ 
  &\vec{\dot{R}}_o=\vec{\dot{R}}+\dot{S}\,\vec{u}\\
  &\vec{\ddot{R}}_o=\vec{\ddot{R}}+\ddot{S}\,\vec{u}\\
  &\text{and}\\
  &\dot{S}=S\,\tilde{\vec{\omega}}\\
  &\ddot{S}=S\,\tilde{\vec{\dot{\omega}}}+\dot{S}\,\tilde{\vec{\omega}}=
  S\,\tilde{\vec{\dot{\omega}}}+S\,\tilde{\vec{\omega}}^2\\\\
  &\text{$S$ is the rotation matrix between body coordinate system and inertial system }\\
  &\text{$S$ can be constructed out of the euler angels $\varphi_i$},\quad S=S(\vec{\varphi})\\
  &\text{and}\\
  &\vec{\omega}\times \vec{u}=\begin{bmatrix}
                          0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y \\
                          \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\
                          \omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \\
                        \end{bmatrix}
         \begin{bmatrix}
           u_x \\
           u_y \\
           u_z \\
         \end{bmatrix}\equiv\tilde{\vec{\omega}}\,\vec{u}\\
&\Rightarrow\\
 &m\,\ddot{\vec{R}}=\sum_{cm} F\mapsto\\
 &m\,\ddot{R}_o-m\,S\,\left(\tilde{\vec{\dot{\omega}}}+\tilde{\vec{\omega}}^2\right)\,\vec{u}=\sum_{cm} F\qquad(2)\\
 &\text{multiply equation (2) from the left with $s^T$}\\
 &m\,\ddot{R}_B-m\,\,\left(\tilde{\vec{\dot{\omega}}}+\tilde{\vec{\omega}}^2\right)\,\vec{u}=S^T\,\sum_{cm} F\qquad(3)\\
 &\text{with  } \ddot{R}_B=S^T\,\ddot{R}_o
\end{align*}

**Rotation**

\begin{align*}
  &I_{cm}\,\vec{\dot{\omega}}+\tilde{\vec{\omega}}\,I_{cm}\,\vec{\omega}=\sum_{cm} \tau\qquad(4)\\
  &\text{if we go from center of mass coordinate system to $o$  coordinate system we obtain }\\
  &I_{o}\,\vec{\dot{\omega}}+\tilde{\vec{\omega}}\,I_{o}\,\vec{\omega}=\sum_{cm} \tau+\tilde{\vec{u}}\,\sum_{cm} F\qquad(5)\\
  &\text{with the inertia tensor } I_o=I_{cm}+m\,\tilde{\vec{u}}
\end{align*}
\newpage
Equation (3) and (5)
\begin{align*}
& \begin{bmatrix}
   m\,E_3 & m\,\tilde{\vec{u}} \\\\
   0 & I_o \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \ddot{\vec{R}}_B \\\\
   \dot{\vec{\omega}} \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
   m\,\tilde{\vec{\omega}}^2\,\vec{u}+S^T(\vec{\varphi})\,\sum_{cm} F \\\\
   -\tilde{\vec{\omega}}\,I_{o}\,\vec{\omega}+\sum_{cm} \tau+\tilde{\vec{u}}\,\sum_{cm} F \\
 \end{bmatrix}\quad ,\text{and}\quad
 \dot{\vec{\varphi}}=A(\vec{\varphi})\,\vec{\omega}\\\\
 &\text{The   position vector in inertial system $\vec{R}_o$ can be obtain out of}\\
 &\ddot{\vec{R}}_o=S\,\ddot{\vec{R}}_B\quad
 \Rightarrow\\
 &\dot{\vec{R}}_o=\int\left(S(\vec{\varphi})\,\ddot{\vec{R}}_B\,dt\right)+\dot{\vec{R}}_o(0)\\
 &\vec{R}_o=\int\left(\dot{\vec{R}}_o\right)+\vec{R}_o(0)
\end{align*}